# Update mysql field with addition users if duplicate search is performed

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I have a site where user's searches are tagged with their user id. Right now, if a different user searches a duplicate, it adds +1 to a count field I have, yet, it still keeps the original user's id who searched it.

How can I start making an "array" of user ID's for the userId field in my table on a duplicate search.

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO trending (searchstring, timecount, userSearch) VALUES('$_POST[contentVar]', NOW(), '$uid') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1";
```

searchstring is the user search, timecount is time, userSearch is the user ID of the user who searched it.

Comment: It looks like you are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. :(

Comment: its a bad way to insert the $_POST like this , check about sql injection

Comment: Besides that... Any ideas on my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SQL-injection**
Never inject super-globals directly into SQL.
With the `update` part you mustn't forget the `set` keyword.

Do it like this:

```
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contentvar']);
$uid = mysql_real_escape_string($uid);
$sql="INSERT INTO trending (searchstring, timecount, userSearch)
      VALUES('$contentvar', NOW(), '$uid') 
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET count = count + 1";
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html
And: [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)

Comment: Thank you for the help in regards to the sql injection. As for the update, I need to add the other user id to the already existing id.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered inserting a new row for each and every search, then you can query the table when you need by $uid and form an array that way.

Comment: yes, but I want to keep a count of the duplicates to make a trending function.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible approaches: 1. create a new table where the ids of the users will be kept or modify the `userSearch` column to hold a serialized array. Both cannot be done by simply modifying the `UPDATE` query.